# Bad perfomance with Android plugin for Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When dimensions of a project start being considerable the plugin of Android for Eclipse starts not working properly and also very slow, when it comes to XML modifications, refractoring the code from the XML files becomes tedious. Also sometimes it doesnt recognize strings resources. And I have to clean the project(which sometimes is like the solution for windows of restart the computer...)

Do you know about solutions to improve this behaviour? As I think it will be really helpful.

Comment: Try to use as few platform versions as possible. Usually i only use the lowest i support and the most recent which makes it somewhat faster.

Comment: Yup, Eclipse sure is a boated hog of an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things impacting eclipse's performance: I/O and memory....

I/O: Buy Good SSD disk. Full stop.

Memory:

There are few ways to improve performance:

1) include the following lines in eclipse.ini (with at least these values):

```
-vmargs
-Xms160m
-Xmx2048m
```

(that is if you have enough memory)

2) Use 32-bit eclipse on 64-bit system
That might be surprising, and it is only valid if you have not very big amount of memory (few gigs). 32-bit eclipse take about 50-60% of memory comparing to 64-bit one - the thing is that in 64-bit java every object/field etc. take 2x much memory as in 32-bit java. Until java supports (so far experimental) compressed references taking less space, it might well be that memory limits will be hit with 64-bit version where 320bit should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can run slow if you have too many projects open, especially if the projects are very large. I remember when i had like 3 sample projects open at the same time and eclipse went from running on 200 meg to running at 500 meg, it was really slow untill i closed all the projects i wasnt using, it also depends which type of computer you have, if your computer doesnt have very much ram then eclipse will run slow. My computer cleans projects really slow when i have a bunch of projects open.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that eclipse.ini doesn't contains following line:

```
    CompileThreshold=5
```

I have taken this line from some superfast Eclipse jvm config, but that option just makes compilation terribly slow.